# awk-if with variables doesn't work properly sometimes

Tags: shell, variables, if-statement, awk

In a text, I want to classify my data according to it range.

For example, 8.1,9.1,9.9 are all in [8,10). I used variables called left and right to replace 8 and 10 respectively in awk-if. But it doesn't work properly.

My data like this:

```
9.1 aa
9.2 bb
10.1 cc
11.9 dd
```

Then my scripts like this:

```
left=8;right=10                    #left=10;right=12
echo "["$left","$right"]:"
cat data | awk '{if(($1>="'$left'")&&($1<"'$right'")) print $2}' | xargs
```

The result is empty.

```
[8,10]:
```

But if I use 8 and 10 directly (without variables), it's OK. And when I use left=10, right=12, it works also properly.

I also found when left=98, right=100, it also didn't work. So why sometimes it doesn't work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The [`cat` is useless](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and the `xargs` is similarly dubious at best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are performing string comparison but want numeric comparison. Just swap the quotes:

```
 left=8;right=10 #left=10;right=12
 echo "["$left","$right"]:"
 cat data | awk '{if(($1>='"$left"')&&($1<'"$right"')) print $2}' | xargs
```

Answer (score 2):

With awk's option `-v`:

```
left=8;right=10
awk -v l="$left" -v r="$right" '{if($1>=l&&$1<r) print $2}' data
```

or with environment variables:

```
export left=8 right=10
awk '{if($1>=ENVIRON["left"]&&$1<ENVIRON["right"]) print $2}' data
```

Output:

```
aa
bb
```

Comment: Never use a variable named `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. For example, it's extremely hard to tell if `$1>=l` in your code is comparing `$1` to the number `1` or the letter `l`.